# Render an SVG icon inside a button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button, icons

I have an SVG in a folder `icon.svg`, I'm trying to render it in a button along with text. Specifically, it's the Google icon and i'm trying to render it next to some text that says "SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE"

I'm importing the SVG as is and trying to pass it next to the button but, the file path is rendering instead:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
            <button>{SVG}SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That renders a button that says `/static/media/Icon.a1611096.svgSIGN IN WITH GOOGLE`

How is one supposed to render the icon *inside* the button properly?

**EDIT:** I've been messing with the icon and the button and got close:

https://codesandbox.io/s/10k7rr3rp4

Answer (score 5):

First you have to save the icon in `assets` folder.
 Then import it into the component which you want to use in

```
import {ReactComponent as Logo} from '../../assets/google.svg';
```

Now you can use it like a component

```
<button>
   <Logo className='logo' /> Sign in with Google
</button>
```

Comment: The only problem was, cannot just display the only logo without text. In such a case, we need to add min-width to the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the require function as follows:

```
<button><img src={require(SVG)} alt="test" />SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE</button>
```

Comment: Tried that, it's displaying the path instead of the actual `svg` element:

`Error: Cannot find module '/static/media/Icon.a1611096.svg'`

 It must be the way I'm importing it?

importing it as: `import SVG from './images/Icon.svg';`
 I also tried importing it as a component :

`import { ReactComponent as SVGIcon } from './images/Icon.svg';`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you create the project using create-react-app? if yes importing it like this import SVG from './images/Icon.svg'; then putting it in src of image should work fine. but if you're writing your own webpack configs you need to make sure you've discussed the related configs
check the following link:
https://itnext.io/react-svg-images-and-the-webpack-loader-to-make-them-play-nice-2d177ae34d2b

Answer (score 0):

another solution could be to use styled-components with ::before pseudo element.
i just moved the images folder to the public folder.

[live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/my0n3ylqq8?fontsize=14)