# Custom svg image "button" for React Router Link

Tags: reactjs, svg, button

I am trying to customize a React Router Link "button" with a custom SVG image. I have found different sources with custom icons to be used, or solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961563/render-an-svg-icon-inside-a-button/55961660) but did not succeed with custom image file.The Router link is part of a dynamic list:

```
<td><Link to={} data-id={} className={"btn btn-success"}>Add new image</Link></td>
```

And the text would be moved as a hint upon mouseover effect. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

So i have tried with  and  with src. Of course it didnt render and run into error.

I have imported

```
import { ReactComponent as AddNewImageIcon } from "./WebAppButtons/AddPhoto.svg";

  <td><Link to={``} data-id={} className={""}>{<AddNewImageIcon />}Add new image</Link></td>
```

In this way, it renders, however, there is a weird image background appears under the image:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkB6l.jpg)

Did not experience it with SVG files before. Is there any way to remove it or is it the behavior of SVG file in react? The other question is, should it be wrapped into DIV that would be formatted with SCSS or this component can be formatted with SCSS as well, eg.:width/height/hover etc.?

Comment: _"but did not succeed with custom image file"_ What have you tried? What was wrong with it? You should post your code and probably read [how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i have edited the question accordingly with the update of my experiment.